# Subset of the span

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove or disprove (using an example) the following statement. If $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\}$ and $B= \{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_m\}$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ for which $\text{span(A)} \subseteq \text{span(B)}$, then $A \subseteq B$.

In this problem, does $A \subseteq B$ simply mean that vector of $A$ in its exact form must be in $B$?

If so, then is this a good counterexample:

$A = \{[5 \space 0 ]^T \}, \space \space B = \{[1 \space 0]^T, [0 \space 1]^T   \} $

Comment: Your  counterexample is o.K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $A\subseteq B$ means that $\forall a \in A, a\in B$ (put into words, this means that every element of $A$ is an element of $B$). So your counterexample is correct, indeed.